# Kendo ListView search doesn't work properly with filtered data

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a datasource with a filter applied to it. When I enable filterable search for the listview, it wipes out the original filter on the datasource. How can I get it to search WITHIN the filtered data subset?

Here is the issue in action: http://jsfiddle.net/KS7dB/. It is filtered by {b: "2B"}. Start entering "ds" in the search and it wipes out the filter and starts searching everything instead of only the filtered subset. Any idea on how to fix this behavior?

```
var ds1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        stagename: "ds1 A",
        b: "1b"
    }, {
        stagename: "ds1 B",
        b: "2b"
    }, {
        stagename: "ds1 C",
        b: "2b"
    }, {
        stagename: "ds1 D",
        b: "2c"
    }, {
        stagename: "ds1 E",
        b: "2c"
    }],
    filter: {
        field: 'b',
        operator: 'eq',
        value: '2b'
    }
});

$("#stages_listview").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: ds1,
    template: $("#stages_listview_template1").html(),
    filterable: {
        field: 'stagename',
        operator: 'contains',
        ignoreCase: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did spent some time digging into this and the problem is that as soon as you create filter on your listview, in practice that is a filter on the underlining data source, they are not two separate cumulative filters . Therefore behaviour you observed seems to be correct.

Work around options:

1. override the filter function on the data source so it takes argument
   passed to it via listview and always append the default data source
   filter. Something alongside these lines. I have to admit I didn't
   manage to craft final and functional solution.

   ```
   lw.dataSource.filter = function() {
   arguments[arguments.length]= { field: "b", operator: "eq", value: "2b" };
   arguments.length += 1;
   var result = lw.dataSource.originalfilter.apply(this, arguments);
   return result;
   ```

   }
2. filter server side